# How to check if the view pager is at last element while writing unit in android

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit

I was writing a junit test where I wanted to know whether the view pager is at the last element or not. How can I do this. Actually I am a begineer at writing unit tests.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get current position from `ViewPager` usign `getCurrentItem()`. This value you can compare with number of the elements in `ViewPager`'s adapter.

Remember that items in `ViewPager` are indexed from 0 (so `0, 1, 2, 3, ...`), but number of items (in adapter) in amount of elements.

### In kotlin:

```
val result = if (view_pager.adapter == null) {
    // Adapter did not set
    false
} else {
    // Check if "current position" equal "number of elements
    view_pager.currentItem == view_pager.adapter?.count?.minus(1)
}
```

### In Java:

```
boolean result;

if (viewPager.getAdapter() == null) {
    // Adapter did not set
    result = false;
} else {
    // Check if "current position" equal "number of elements
    result = viewPager.getCurrentItem() == viewPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1;
}
```

Comment: In kotlin you can write it with `view_pager.adapter?.let { ... } ?: false`

Comment: @Ircover yes, you can write in many ways. My above is shorter and more similar to Java.